# how to truncate a PRF on n bits to PRF on t bits where t < n?

Tags: encryption, pseudo-random-function, format-preserving

Dan Boneh's courersa lecture on [format preserving encryption](https://class.coursera.org/crypto/lecture/45)  at 5.50 mins , talks about truncating a PRF on $n$ bits to PRF on $t$ bits.

The approach is by appending $(n-t)$ zeros to input $t$ bits then applying AES on $n$ bits and truncating it back to $t$ bits . He says there are better ways to do it but does not mention how . anybody has idea on better ways to truncating PRF on $t$ bits when $t \ll n$ .

Comment: Better, in what way?  The construction Boneh provides is a perfectly reasonable choice.  Unless you can define in what objective metric/criteria you would use to define "better", I don't think this question is well-defined.

Comment: @D.W even i was not clear by Boneh's comment that there are better ways to do it . so thought of checking with the community